# 3D model photogrammetry in blender software

Tags: photogrammetry

I would like to know a 3D photogrammetry model is it more difficult to read in blender versus a normal or cartoon model ? I send screenshots of 3D photogrammetry model (if I'm not mistaken) and normal model, to better understand. Also, can I modify or customize a 3D photogrammetry model in the blender software, without difficulty ? I mean can I take the cars off the streets from the 3D photogrammetry model and other things, if I want ? I noticed that the colletion scene at the top right (screenshot) of the 3D photogrammetry model has fewer files than the 3D cartoon or normal model. Does this mean that the 3D photogrammetry mode is nothing more than a block, even impossible to modify ? Help please [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the only way to remove things like vehicles in a photogrammetry model, is to remove the vertices that the vehicle is made out of.
I would assume the photogrammetry model would be harder to read because it's not as clean as the other model and it has texture on 100% of it.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Which one do you suggest to create a video game ? The 3D photogrammetry model or the normal / cartoon 3D model and why ? Because it's my project ! Help please

Comment: It really depends on the type of game and the target platform. If this a GTA type of game where your player walks or drives into town, I say definitely the cartoony model is best, but if it's some kind of "spot the difference" game, maybe the photogrammetry is better. You must also look at the polygon number, if your game targets mobile phone for instance, you want it to be as low as possible. Also, make sure that your resources are licensed to be used in a video game if you plan on releasing it to the public.

Comment: thank you very much, it makes sense